# Message sent to deallocated instance, crash in UIKit framework, how to debug?

Tags: uikit, crash, zombie-process

Hey all you smart guys;

A tough crash bug debugging for many days but still don't find the root cause, thirst for your tips and guidance.

It is a a table view controller, but more complicated since we have added many other UI controls in. Using tool Zombie to assist debugging and find crash dues to the deallocated table view still receives outside event.

Questions.

1. See the following call stack capture by Zombie, I've no idea which unexpected event is still sent out. Any method available which will help to debug into UIKit framework inside?
2. I am new to IPhone programming, I want to know if you meet such issue, what methods you will try to seek the root cause? How to try? How to suspend the crash points?

I have done many experiments and all of them have been proved failure so far. Need your help, any idea and discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
@interface FavoriteDetailViewController : UITableViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate,FavoritesEditDelegate>
```

[image: Crash call stack, capture by zombies.]

Comment: Have you tried the 'Analyze' option form Xcode?

Comment: Yes, no defect found by XCode Analysis tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

```
-[ChaptersContentController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance
UIKit`-[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:]
```

Setting the datasource and the delegate of my tableView to nil in the dealloc method helped me

```
-(void)dealloc {
self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
self.tableView.delegate   = nil;
...
```

Comment: Add self.tableView.dataSource = nil; is enough to fix the crash.